# How can find the child widget in therecipe/qt

Tags: qt, glide-golang

I want to change the child widget's size when it's parent widget's size changed, but i can't find it's child widget in parent widget. My code such as that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/core"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/gui"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/widgets"
    "os"
)

type MainWin struct {
    *widgets.QWidget
}

func NewMainWin() *MainWin {
    win := &MainWin{
        widgets.NewQWidget(nil, core.Qt__Widget),
    }
    win.initUI()
    return win
}

func (m *MainWin) initUI() {
    m.Resize2(1000, 680)
    m.SetWindowTitle("demo")
    icon := gui.NewQIcon5("./skin/image/logo.png")
    m.SetWindowIcon(icon)

    m.ConnectResizeEvent(func(event *gui.QResizeEvent) {
        width := m.Width()
        height := m.Height()
        tab := m.FindChild("TabWidget", core.Qt__FindDirectChildrenOnly)
        fmt.Println(tab.IsWidgetType())
        tabw := m.Find(tab.PtrI)
        fmt.Println(tabw.IsWidgetType())
        fmt.Println(tabw)
        tabw.Resize2(width, height)
        fmt.Println(tabw.Height(), tabw.Width())
    })

}

func main() {
    app := widgets.NewQApplication(len(os.Args), os.Args)
    win := NewMainWin()
    tab := widgets.NewQTabWidget(win)
    tb1 := widgets.NewQLabel(nil, core.Qt__Widget)
    tb1.SetText("Hello")
    tab.SetObjectName("TabWidget")

    tab.AddTab(tb1, "Hello")
    win.Show()
    os.Exit(app.Exec())
}
```

the **FindChild("TabWidget", core.Qt__FindDirectChildrenOnly)** can find the child, but it is a QObject, it's  **IsWidgetType() is true**, and i can't use it to change it's size, it is not use.
so I think i can use the Find(ptr) to get a QWidget, but i found a "&{{{0 widgets.QWidget}} {{0 widgets.QWidget}}}" struct. What should i do?

I use **SetObjectName()** to define child name, and i try use **SetAccessibleName()** to set yet.
But not used.
therecipe/qt QWidget have a function **Parent()** return the child widget's parent object, and also have a function **ParentWidget()** return it's parent widget. But for a parent, Can't it find a function to get a child widget?